# But I already ate it! (Should this question be closed?)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Should this question be closed? [Is an unrefrigerated canned ham safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44996/is-an-unrefrigerated-canned-ham-safe-to-eat)

If it (and the inevitable future questions like it) should be closed, can we add the poison control line to our list of stock reasons for closure so it shows up on this block?

[image: closed]

To be used only in the event of somebody asking if something *they already ate* is unsafe and the answer is yes?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is something of a special case - from what I can tell, this sort of post-ingestion question doesn't come up that often.  However, it may be worth revising the stock answer included above to include a note about urgent assistance, and possibly a link to Google with localized results **[like so](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=poison%20control)**.  Even if uncommon, I don't think this is the type of situation that should be ignored.